# why does my program skip steps using getline()?

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04

I think my program skips steps because I use getline() inside While and For loops without using cin.clear() and cin.ignore(). If I'm right, where will I have to insert them?

I tried to write the code with cin.clear() and cin.ignore(10000, '\n') after each getline() (really I don't know how these functions work properly, I found them surfing on Google) and the code doesn't work correctly.

The code is  :

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  string S;
  cout<<"insert test....input exaple: test 1"<<endl;
  getline(cin, S);

  while(S!="-1"){

    cout<<"START WHILE"<<endl;
    int nB = 0; //number of Lego Bricks;

    cout<<"insert number of Lego bricks"<<endl;
    cin>>nB;
    for(int i=0; i<nB; i++){

      cout<<"START FOR"<<endl;
      cout<<"insert Lego brick (the number of faces must be even)....input example: NameBrick -> face1 face2 face3 face4...."<<endl;
      getline(cin, S);
    }
    getline(cin, S);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hasn't even opened the question, but when I saw the title, I *knew* you were intermixing calls to `cin >>` and `getline`. Don't use the `>>` operator! It is *evil.* Depending on the context, the particular overload of the operator and the history/state of the stream object, it may or may not consume and/or stop at whitespace, newlines or other character classes. "Solutions" which suggest `clear()` and `ignore()` are not real solutions – they *sometimes* are able to eliminate *some* of the symptoms, but they don't mitigate the *cause* of the errors.

Comment: What do you mean by skips steps? What does your program try to do?

Comment: So, in short, the solution should be to just use `getline()` *always.* If you need input of types other than string, you can carry out string-to-whatever conversions (e. g. for numeric values, there's `std::stoi` and `std::stod`, etc.)

Comment: (*haven't, silly me, I'm too tired.)

Comment: Could you explain to us, in simpler language, what this program is supposed to do? The current code seems to be something like: (1) enter a line of text, then (2) read an integer `nB`, then (3) read `nB` lines, then (4) read another final line. What is this all about? Please put this plain clear description into the question

Answer (score 0):

```
   cout<<"insert number of Lego bricks"<<endl;
   cin>>nB;
```

This is the problem. getLine() keeps reading until the next newline character. Let us say that '|' is our newline symbol.

When you write something into the terminal or when you are reading from file you have many lines to work through.

Example input(Greeting, name, age and hobby):

Hello.|

Magnus Elden|

24|

Tennis|

GetLine() will give you the entire line. The first call to getLine() will return the string "Hello." and stop since it reached a newline character, '|'.
The important part is that it stops AFTER the newline character.
Thus, the next time the first character it reads is the 'M' in "Magnus Elden".

When you get to the age part of the input, you use cin which only read the first item, be it a string or a number. As such it will stop BEFORE the newline character. The next time you call getLine() it reads until a newline character comes, but since the newline character still remains in the buffer getLine() returns immediately with "" as its return value.

That is why it seems to skip a step.

Step by step breakdown:
You input your greeting "Hello." and the buffer will then look like this:
Buffer:Hello.|
Let us say that the start of the reading is denoted by a ^. These are the steps.

Step 1.

Input:Hello.

Buffer:Hello.|

```
     ^
```

Function call:getLine()

Return value:"Hello."

Buffer:

Step 2.

Input:Magnus Elden

Buffer:Magnus Elden.|

```
     ^
```

Function call: getLine()

Return value:"Magnus Elden"

Buffer:

Step 3.

Input:24

Buffer:24|

```
     ^
```

Function call: cin

Return value:24

Buffer:|

Step 4.

Input:Tennis.

Buffer:|Tennis.|

```
     ^
```

Function call: getLine()   //Remember that it runs until the first newline '|'.

Return value:""

Buffer:Tennis|

Just change the code bit to:

```
cout<<"insert number of Lego bricks"<<endl;
getLine(cin, s);
nB = atoi(s.c_str());
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`getline(cin,s)` will do what you expect. The rest of the line (except the newline itself) is stored in `s`. And, crucially, the newline itself will be extracted and discarded.

So, if you call `getline(cin,s)` multiple times, each line will be read once, as you expect.

Similarly, assuming `x` in an `int`,  `cin >> x` will read an integer. Multiple consecutive calls to `cin >> x` will read numbers from the input into `x`. Each time you call `cin>>x` it will skip over any whitespace *before* the number, then read the number. So, if you have a set of numbers, perhaps on the same line separated by spaces, or perhaps on different lines separated by newlines, then `cin>>x` will read them for you.

But it will not read-and-discard any whitespace after the number. Whitespace is discarded at the start of each call to `cin>>x` (i.e. *before* the number itself is read), but *not* *after* the number is read.

The problem occurs if you have a `cin>>x` followed by a `getline`. Imagine you type a number and then press enter. `cin>>x` will consume the number. but `cin>>x` will *not* consume the newline. Then, the getline will attempt to read the *rest* of the line. It will not try to read the *next* line. We're are still stuck on the same line as the number. You probably hit Enter immediately after entering the number, therefore the "rest of the line" is just an empty string.

There's a difference between "typing a number" and "typing a number followed by hitting the Enter key"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
I solved replacing cin>> with getline how many of you suggested.

precisely:

```
cout<<"insert number of Lego bricks"<<endl;
cin>>nB;
```

with

```
cout<<"insert number of Lego bricks"<<endl;
getLine(cin, s);
nB = atoi(s.c_str());
```